# How to start unity after boot into command line with "text"-option?

Tags: unity, command-line

I want my system to boot terminal only, but be able to launch Unity once logged in.  I've edited `/etc/default/grub` from :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash text"
```

and my system launches to the terminal fine, but when I try to launch unity I get:

> WARNING: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to : 0
>   compiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display : 0

Everything goes back to normal when I restore the original GRUB configuration, so it looks to me like nothing is actually broken.

I'm running in a VM, and have now tested this with a clean install of Ubuntu, as well as with the Amahi installation I am trying to test.  The same error occurs with the clean install.

So how can I actually start unity after a system start that doens't start it directly?

Comment: Are you using 12.04?

Comment: How are you trying to start Unity? Are you using `startx`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `startx` command load only the default desktop environment without Unity or other user interface. The `startx unity` command can do this job, but I do not recommend it. You can test it and you'll see why.

To load with success the X display manager along with Unity from TTY, use next command:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Comment: To exit back to the shell, just do "sudo service lightdm stop" and CTRL-Alt-F1?

Comment: Did this answer work for you? `sudo service lightdm start` gives me the login screen but after that when I login everything is broken.

Comment: This answer did work for me.  The only issue is when entering Unity this way the screen resolution has gone to a very low resolution... Maybe 800x600?  But this is really OK as everything seems to still work.